# Gracefully Terminate a Process from DSC or chocolateyinstall.ps1

Tags: powershell, dsc, chocolatey

You can gracefully terminate a program normally by:

```
Get-Process "*notepad*" | Foreach-Object {$_.CloseMainWindow()}
```

I'm using a DSC configuration with Package or a cChoco resource to install a package. I'd like to warn the user the program is updating (msg * "Closing in 5 minutes" for example) and then attempt to close the program gracefully.

I'm unable to get this to work in a *Chocolatey package (chocolateyinstall.ps1)* or in a Desired State Configuration Script. I've also tried it running as a task scheduled script with no luck. I'm guessing because the process is running in a different context that DSC/Task Scheduler is running in.

I'm able to kill the process with `Get-Process "*notepad*" | Stop-Process`, but that just kills the process.

Is there any way I can do this? I'm guessing this would be the same as calling `CloseMainWindow()` on a process with a login script.

Comment: CloseMainWindow uses GetWindowLong WINAPI which AFAIK requires privileges to read the other process memory. I don't know about DSC but you may try opening the running DSC process manually via marshalled WINAPI functions: OpenProcess, then OpenProcessToken, LookupPrivilegeValue for SeDebugPrivilege, and use it in AdjustTokenPrivileges.

Comment: DSC is running as system, there shouldn't be any problem with that

Comment: well, I'm not a big expert in that, but assuming `system` has got highest privileges possible, why not?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that you can't use `msg * "message here"` in a Chocolatey package. If you run it outside of DSC, does it work?